# Loading images from firestore in image slider

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, image-slider

I'm trying to load the images in an image slider from firestore. The image urls are there in firestore. I'm using the following library https://github.com/denzcoskun/ImageSlideshow for image slider, but it shows error instead of images.

[Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIfLm.png)

[Logcat Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62qiw.png)

[Image of firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KAjC.png)

This is the java code:

```
public class preview_product extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private String position;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private ImageSlider imageSlider;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_product_preview);

        imageSlider = findViewById(R.id.image_slider);
        final List<SlideModel> displayImages = new ArrayList<>();

        Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
        position = intent.get("key").toString();



        db.collection("Store").document("name").collection("prod").document(position).collection("details").document("product_id").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot)
            {

        List<String> Urls = (List<String>) documentSnapshot.get("Images");

                displayImages.add(new SlideModel(Urls.toString(), ScaleTypes.FIT));

                imageSlider.setImageList(displayImages,ScaleTypes.FIT);
                imageSlider.startSliding(3000);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: No sir, the app does not crash. I get the word "error" written in place of images in image slider. Logcat has all the image urls. Have added the images in the question.

Comment: Are all those valid URLs?

Comment: Yes sir, each one of them opens an image in browser.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I have added the image sir.

Comment: The reference you are using `db.collection("Store").document("name").collection("prod").document(position).collection("details").document("product_id")` doesn't correspond with we are using in the screenshot, right?

Comment: It does sir, I have just changed tow things to avoid confusion. The original one is -  db.collection("Store").document("uniquename.TFTVHvZaHOIxjYLnHvwc").collection("products").document(position).collection("about").document("product_id").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>()

Comment: So please provide the correct reference. Besides that, only the content of that array are you interested in, right?

Comment: Yes, want the images of array to come in the image slider.

Comment: What is the correct reference? As we cannot see it in the screenshot.

Comment: This is the correct one - db.collection("Store").document("uniquename.TFTVHvZaHOIxjYLnHvwc").collection("products").document(position).collection("about").document("product_id").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>()...

Comment: The path is long, not covered in the screenshot. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've copied the link of the webpage-showing the image ,instead of the link of actual image.
Try opening the image in a new tab, and then copy the link from the address-bar.

[Maybe, this is what you've copied !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihyzl.jpg)

[This is what you should try coping instead !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m4fF.jpg)

Hope this helps!